# Get all users of an Ado or TFS project

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, tfs, ado.net

I am unable to find any ADO .net client libraries/rest apis to find all the users related to a particular project, project can be belong to ADO server or TFS (>2013) and ADO service.

I used GraphHttpClient but it is deprecated now and can not be used with TFS, I guess. I am unable to find its documentation either. Also I am facing trouble how to use Microsoft Graph client to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To get the users of Azure DevOps Service, we can use the API: [Users - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) with the variable `scopeDescriptor` to get the list of user in one project.

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users?scopeDescriptor={scopeDescriptor}&api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Refer to the following steps:

Step1: Use Rest API: [List all projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and get the project ID.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0
```

Step2:Get the one project **scopeDescriptor** via [Descriptors - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/descriptors/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/descriptors/{ProjectID}?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

For example:

[image]

We can record the value(scp...) of the value field in the response. The value is scopeDescriptor.

Step3: Add the related values to the Rest API:

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users?scopeDescriptor={scopeDescriptor}&api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Then we could only get the list of users in one project.

If you need to run the Rest APIs in TFS or Azure DevOps Server, you can change to use the related Rest API version.

For example: You can check it in the dropdown list of the doc.

[image]

**Update:**

To get the users in the TFS or Azure DevOps project,  you can use the [client API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/) you mentioned above to retrieve the user list.

You can check the group: `[projectname]\\Project Valid Users` to get all users in the project.

Here is an example:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace Getuserlist

{

    class Program

    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            TfsConfigurationServer tcs = new TfsConfigurationServer(new Uri("http://server:8080/tfs"));

            IIdentityManagementService ims = tcs.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();

            TeamFoundationIdentity tfi = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, "[projectname]\\Project Valid Users", MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

            TeamFoundationIdentity[] ids = ims.ReadIdentities(tfi.Members, MembershipQuery.None, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("userlist.txt"))

                foreach (TeamFoundationIdentity id in ids)

                {
                    if (id.Descriptor.IdentityType == "System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity")

                    { Console.WriteLine(id.DisplayName); }
                    //{ Console.WriteLine(id.UniqueName); }

                    file.WriteLine("[{0}]", id.DisplayName);
                }

            var count = ids.Count(x => ids.Contains(x));
            Console.WriteLine(count);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ty for this, but just asking Is there any client library in ado .net sdk to do the same thing?

Comment: @AmanVarshney I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method in .net sdk can directly achieve the same requirement. Currently, it supports list all users in the whole organization instead of the single project. And the parameter: scopeDescriptor  doesn't support when using .net sdk. the I suggest that you can consider using Rest APIs to achieve it.  Rest APIs can work in both Azure DevOps Service, tfs and Azure DevOps Server

Comment: Ty again, Ya I find out recently while using GraphHttpClient that .net sdk does not support scopeDescriptor in ListUsersAsync. But in my use case it is not possible to use RestApis as I am using client libraries from beginning in the project and also I am working with different tfs versions so setting api-version based on what tfs version I am using is troublesome, because I don't know what tfs version it is, I only got access to TFS or ado collection uri.

Comment: Hello, @Kevin I am unable to get descriptor for my TFS project or ADO server 2020 with this api. It works fine with ADO service (on cloud).

Comment: @AmanVarshney Yes, check the API doc, the API only supports Cloud service.Please check the update of the answer. We can use the c# client  to get the users in the tfs/azure devops server project.